# Properties of first-countable spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Hi I have questions regarding first-countable spaces. I just want to confirm something:

The following are properties regarding limits and continuity of first countable spaces on Wikipedia:

1. If $f$ is a function on a first-countable space then $f$ has a limit $L$ at the point $a$ if and only if for every sequence $x_{n} \rightarrow a$ where $x_{n} \neq a$ for all $n$ we have $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow L$.
2. If $f$ is a function on a first-countable space, then $f$ is continuous if and only if whenever $x_{n} \rightarrow a$ then $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(a)$.

Assume that $f$ is defined on an open domain $\Omega$. I want confirm that property 1 allows $x \in \overline{\Omega}$ but property 2 requires that $a \in \Omega$?

Secondly, I want to confirm that if $x \in \overline{\Omega} \setminus \Omega$ and we assume that $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$ then the only thing we can get from property 2 is that for any $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ it follows that $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow L$, where from 1 it follows that $L = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$?

Thanks.